# PHP failed to open stream: Cannot allocate memory

Tags: php, warnings, jelastic

I've got this warning log early by the morning on my php saying that it couldn't allocate memory when I was trying to connect to my database.

This is the log:

```
[26-May-2017 08:41:12 UTC] PHP Warning:  include(../../../System/Functions/LocalDB.php): failed to open stream: Cannot allocate memory in /LocalSettings.php on line 4
```

The only thing in that line is an include to the `LocalDB.php` file.

It was the first time it happened and this file is executed several times a day and the server is hosted on a Jelastic environment.

This memory allocation error may be because the server ran out of memory?

**EDIT**

Also, here is the monitor graph of the server on the time of the error, everything looks normal.
[image]

Comment: Most probably yes. Maybe a lot of query hit the server at the same time and it got overwhelmed.

Comment: Hello Rafael, if you will provide hoster platform and environment name, we can take a look, at this issue.

Comment: @Jelastic The server is hosted by Locaweb on Brazil, should I contact their support or you can take a look anyway?

Comment: We can take a look, just provide us also environment name.

Comment: Ok, but this is a production server, so there will be no downtime or restarts right?

Comment: We do not perform such actions as a restart without customer's permission. We will not restart your production environment.

Comment: Please, notice that we are still waiting for the additional information in order to help you in this case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)